# I need to make a high-score list for this Javascript game

Tags: javascript, html

I hope you can give me a hand with this. My idea is to show a list of high-scores after the game is finished for a Doodle Jump project (javascript). The high-scores are presented successfully as you will see in my code, but the presentation is poor. Hence, I want to show them in a blank page, if possible using the same html. I will leave my code for you to reproduce the issue and help me. I thought about some document command, but you tell me.

Thanks in advance.

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  const grid = document.querySelector('.grid')
  const doodler = document.createElement('div')
  const unMutedIcon = document.createElement('div')
  let doodlerLeftSpace = 50
  let startPoint = 150
  let doodlerBottomSpace = startPoint
  let isGameOver = false
  let platformCount = 5
  let platforms = []
  let upTimerid
  let downTimerId
  let isJumping = true
  let isGoingLeft = false
  let isGoingRight = false
  let leftTimerId
  let rightTimerId
  let score = 0
  let context
  let musicIsPlaying = false
  let copyRightMessage = " DoodleJump version by Santiago Hernandez \n all rights reserved \n Copyright © "
  const NO_OF_HIGH_SCORES = 10;
  const HIGH_SCORES = 'highScores';


  function createDoodler() {
    grid.appendChild(doodler)
    doodler.classList.add('doodler')
    doodlerLeftSpace = platforms[0].left
    doodler.style.left = doodlerLeftSpace + 'px'
    doodler.style.bottom = doodlerBottomSpace + 'px'


  }

  function control(e) {
    if (e.key === "ArrowLeft") {
      moveLeft()

    } else if (e.key === "ArrowRight") {
      moveRight()

    } else if (e.key === "ArrowUp") {
      moveStraight()
    }

  }


  class Platform {
    constructor(newPlatBottom) {
      this.bottom = newPlatBottom
      this.left = Math.random() * 315
      this.visual = document.createElement('div')
      const visual = this.visual
      visual.classList.add('platform')
      visual.style.left = this.left + 'px'
      visual.style.bottom = this.bottom + 'px'
      grid.appendChild(visual)
    }
  }

  function createPlatforms() {
    for (let i = 0; i < platformCount; i++) {
      let platGap = 600 / platformCount
      let newPlatBottom = 100 + i * platGap
      let newPlatform = new Platform(newPlatBottom)
      platforms.push(newPlatform)
      console.log(platforms)
    }
  }

  function movePlatforms() {
    if (doodlerBottomSpace > 200) {
      platforms.forEach(platform => {
        platform.bottom -= 4
        let visual = platform.visual
        visual.style.bottom = platform.bottom + 'px'

        if (platform.bottom < 10) {
          let firstPlatform = platforms[0].visual
          firstPlatform.classList.remove('platform')
          platforms.shift()
          score++

          console.log(score)
          console.log(platforms)
          let newPlatform = new Platform(600)
          platforms.push(newPlatform)
        }
      })
    }
  }

  function jump() {
    clearInterval(downTimerId)
    isJumping = true
    upTimerId = setInterval(function() {
      doodlerBottomSpace += 20
      doodler.style.bottom = doodlerBottomSpace + 'px'
      if (doodlerBottomSpace > startPoint + 200) {
        fall()
      }
    }, 30)
  }

  function fall() {
    clearInterval(upTimerId)
    isJumping = false
    downTimerId = setInterval(function() {
      doodlerBottomSpace -= 5
      doodler.style.bottom = doodlerBottomSpace + 'px'

      if (doodlerBottomSpace <= 0) {
        gameOver()
      }
      platforms.forEach(platform => {
        if ((doodlerBottomSpace >= platform.bottom) &&
          (doodlerBottomSpace <= platform.bottom + 15) &&
          ((doodlerLeftSpace + 60) >= platform.left) &&
          (doodlerLeftSpace <= (platform.left + 85)) &&
          !isJumping
        ) {
          console.log('landed')
          startPoint = doodlerBottomSpace
          jump()

        }
      })

    }, 30)

  }

  function moveLeft() {
    if (isGoingRight) {
      clearInterval(rightTimerId)
      isGoingRight = false
    }
    isGoingLeft = true
    leftTimerId = setInterval(function() {

      if (doodlerLeftSpace >= 0) {
        doodlerLeftSpace -= 5
        doodler.style.left = doodlerLeftSpace + 'px'
      } else moveRight()

    }, 30)
  }

  function moveRight() {
    if (isGoingLeft) {
      clearInterval(leftTimerId)
      isGoingLeft = false
    }
    isGoingRight = true
    rightTimerId = setInterval(function() {
      if (doodlerLeftSpace <= 340) {
        doodlerLeftSpace += 5
        doodler.style.left = doodlerLeftSpace + 'px'
      } else moveLeft()

    }, 30)
  }

  function moveStraight() {
    isGoingRight = false
    isGoingLeft = false
    clearInterval(rightTimerId)
    clearInterval(leftTimerId)


  }



  function gameOver() {
    console.log('GAME OVER')
    isGameOver = true
    try {
      context.pause()
      while (grid.firstChild) {
        grid.removeChild(grid.firstChild)
      }

      grid.innerHTML = score
      clearInterval(upTimerId)
      clearInterval(downTimerId)
      clearInterval(leftTimerId)
      clearInterval(rightTimerId)
    } catch (err) {
      console.log('there was an error at gameover')
      while (grid.firstChild) {
        grid.removeChild(grid.firstChild)
      }
      grid.innerHTML = score

      clearInterval(upTimerId)
      clearInterval(downTimerId)
      clearInterval(leftTimerId)
      clearInterval(rightTimerId)
    }

    checkHighScore()
  }


  function saveHighScore(score, highScores) {
    const name = prompt('You got a highscore! Enter name:');
    const newScore = {
      score,
      name
    };

    // 1. Add to list
    highScores.push(newScore);

    // 2. Sort the list
    highScores.sort((a, b) => b.score - a.score);

    // 3. Select new list
    highScores.splice(NO_OF_HIGH_SCORES);

    // 4. Save to local storage
    localStorage.setItem(HIGH_SCORES, JSON.stringify(highScores));
  };

  function checkHighScore() {
    const highScores = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(HIGH_SCORES)) ? ? [];
    const lowestScore = highScores[NO_OF_HIGH_SCORES - 1] ? .score ? ? 0;

    if (score > lowestScore) {
      saveHighScore(score, highScores); // TODO
      showHighScores(); // TODO
    }

  }

  function showHighScores() {
    const highScores = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(HIGH_SCORES)) ? ? [];
    const highScoreList = document.getElementById('highScores');


    highScoreList.innerHTML = highScores.map((score) =>
      `<li>${score.score} - ${score.name}</li>`
    );
  }

  function start() {
    if (!isGameOver) {
      createPlatforms()
      createDoodler()
      setInterval(movePlatforms, 30)
      jump()
      document.addEventListener('keyup', control)
    }
  }

  document.addEventListener('keypressed', control)

  //attach to buttom
  start()

  //event listener to play music
  document.addEventListener('keypress', function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 32 || e.code == "Space") {
      musicIsPlaying = true
      context = new Audio("Music_level1.wav");
      context.play()
      context.loop = true
    }
  }) //end of event listener
})
```

```css
.grid {
  width: 400px;
  height: 600px;
  background-color: yellow;
  position: relative;
  font-size: 200px;
  text-align: center;
  background-image: url(bluesky_level1.gif);
  background-size: contain;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 400px 600px;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
}

.doodler {
  width: 60px;
  height: 85px;
  position: absolute;
  background-image: url(mariobros_level1.png);
  background-size: contain;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 60px 85px;
  filter: brightness(1.1);
  mix-blend-mode: multiply;
}

#audio {
  display: none
}

.platform {
  width: 85px;
  height: 15px;
  position: absolute;
  background-image: url(platform_tramp_level1.png);
  background-size: contain;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 85px 15px;
}

.volumeIcon {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 570px;
  background-image: url(volumeIconMuted.png);
  background-size: contain;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 30px 30px;
}

.unmutedIcon {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 570px;
  background-image: url(VolumeIcon.png);
  background-size: contain;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 30px 30px;
}

#highScores {
  width: 400px;
  height: 300px;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-family: "Georgia", "Times New Roman";
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<ol id="highScores"></ol>
<div class="grid">
  <div class="volumeIcon"></div>
</div>
```

I included what I think will reproduce the situation. Hope this helps you help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just put:

```
<ol id = "highScores"></ol>
```

within a `<div>` and give that a class that has `display: none` initally? Like this:

```html
<div class="high-scores-container">
  <ol id = "highScores"></ol>
</div>
```

```css
.high-scores-container {
  display: none;
  height: 100%;
}
```

Then when you run your `showHighScores()` function, grab the `high-scores-container` div and change the display to `block` and then at the same time, grab the `grid` div and set that to `display: none`.  That will give you the effect of displaying your high scores on a separate page but you're just doing so with JS/CSS.

Comment: Thank you. This helped solve the problem :)